# Создать аналог встроенной в питон функции range/xrange, который пропускает каждое третье число

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Создать аналог встроенной в питон функции range/xrange. С одним отличием - ваш аналог должен пропускать каждое третье число.
Кто знает как сделать?

Comment: Что вы попытались сделать и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: range/xrange - разные функции. или range из python3?

Comment: вот [вопрос, который несколько реализаций содержит](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1482480/4279), в частности, [`lrange()`](https://github.com/zed/lrange/blob/master/lrange.py#L62)

Comment: противоположное от буквального вопроса: `lambda *a, **kw: range(*a, **kw)[2::3]` (каждое третье выводит)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он из категории "Напишите код за меня"

Comment: @Yuri: нет такой категории. Глупости не говорите.

Answer (score 1):

Слегка грубо. Но работает. [python2-style range]

```
def range_new(value):
    iter_value = -1
    iter_list = []
    step = 0
    while value > iter_value:
        iter_value += 1
        step += 1
        if step != 3:
            iter_list.append(iter_value)
        else:
            step = 0
            continue
    return iter_list[:-1]
```

Comment: Что-то не пойму, как он пропускает каждое третье число?

Comment: Все. Исправил :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def _range(start: int, stop=None, step=1, skip=3) -> iter:
    if stop is None:
        stop = start
        start = 0

    i = 1
    while start < stop:
        if i == skip:
            i = 1
        else:
            yield start
            i += 1
        start += step

print(list(range(1, 12, 2)))
print(list(_range(1, 12, 2, skip=0)))
print(list(_range(1, 12, 2, skip=3)))
```

out:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
[1, 3, 7, 9]
```